# Setting NEW.column in "before update" trigger sets values from previous trigger call

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-10, postgresql-triggers

I'm trying to create a `before update` trigger for a table. Basically, on each row update I need to set additional column on the same row on the same table.

However, for some reason, each trigger call results in setting values from a previous trigger call.

Here's the code for my trigger:

```
create or replace function test_trigger_func() returns trigger as $$
    declare
        v_department  text;
    begin
        select department.name into v_department
        from salesprofile
        left join (
           select department.name from salesprofile join department on department.id = (
               salesprofile.solutionscreteria #>> '{departments, 0}'
           )::int4 where salesprofile.id = NEW.id
        ) department on true
        where salesprofile.id = NEW.id
        group by department.name;
        
        NEW.department = v_department;
        
        raise notice 'DEP: %', v_department;
        raise notice 'NEW DEP: %', NEW.department;
        
        return NEW;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

drop trigger if exists test_trigger on salesprofile;

create trigger test_trigger before update on salesprofile
for each row execute procedure test_trigger_func();
```

The `select` statement inside the `test_trigger_func` function works correctly when run outside the function. But the `raise notice` statements show incorrect (previous) values when the `select` is called from inside the `test_trigger_func` function.

The `salesprofile.solutionscreteria #>> '{departments, 0}'` statement contains the `id` for the row in the `department` table. And I'm trying to set the `department` column on the `salesprofile` table row from the `"department".name` on each `salesprofile` row update (by modifying `NEW.department = ...`).

---

The behaviour I get:

- the `select` statement is perfectly fine and works as expected (when called as is, outside the function).
- when I make the very first update to the `salesprofile` row, the trigger sets the `department` column as `NULL` (the column does not get updated at all);
- when I make the second update to the `salesprofile` row, the trigger sets the `department` column as the value that I was trying to set on the first update;
- when I make the third update to the `salesprofile` row, the trigger sets the `department` column as the value that I was trying to set on the second update;
- and so on...
- if I put the incorrect value to the `salesprofile.solutionscreteria #>> '{departments, 0}'` value, the first trigger update will not cause any errors.
- and then if I set the correct value after that, the trigger will fire with an error (caused by the previous trigger call with incorrect value).

---

I don't get how and why this is happening and I do hope I'm explaining the behaviour in an intelligible way.

Is this the expected behaviour for potgresql triggers? If not, then could you explain what's happening and how to make it work correctly?

Comment: It is a `BEFORE` trigger so it occurs before the `salesprofile` table has the `NEW` data. I'm not entirely following but I'm go to say that this `salesprofile.solutionscreteria #>> '{departments, 0}'` is using the existing(previous) row not the update data the trigger is running on. Have you tried `NEW.solutionscreteria`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This actually did the trick. You can post this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `BEFORE` trigger so it occurs before the `salesprofile` table has the `NEW` data. I'm not entirely following but I'm go to say that this `salesprofile.solutionscreteria #>> '{departments, 0}'` is using the existing(previous) row not the update data the trigger is running on. Try it with `NEW.solutionscreteria`.